# Formatting a number format to date in Google App Scripts

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a script that changes the name of a sheet based on a cell in that sheet. Which works. But I am trying to change the sheet name to a particular date format - 'August 1, 2022'. But the sheet name appears as 'Tue Aug 01 2028 08:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)'   I have tried to add the code '.setNumberFormat('dd.MM.yyyy');' to my code but this doesn't work.

Any ideas? My current code is

```
function changeSheetName( ){
var As = SpreadsheetApp
.getActiveSpreadsheet( )
.getActiveSheet( )
As.setName(As.getRange("A1")
.getValue( ) )
.setNumberFormat('dd.MM.yyyy');
}

function onEdit( ){
changeSheetName( )
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

If cell `A1` already contains a date in the format you want in the sheet name, simply use `Range.getDisplayValue()` instead of `Range.getValue()` and set the sheet name to that text string.

If the date format in cell `A1` is something else, use `Utilities.formatDate()`, like this:

```
/**
* Simple trigger that runs each time the user hand edits the spreadsheet.
*
* @param {Object} e The onEdit() event object.
*/
function onEdit(e) {
  if (!e) {
    throw new Error(
      'Please do not run the onEdit(e) function in the script editor window. '
      + 'It runs automatically when you hand edit the spreadsheet.'
    );
  }
  changeSheetName_(e);
}


/**
* Changes the active sheet name to the date in cell A1 of the sheet.
*
* @param {Object} e The onEdit() event object.
*/
function changeSheetName_(e) {
  const sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const date = sheet.getRange('A1').getValue();
  if (Object.prototype.toString.call(date) !== '[object Date]') {
    return;
  }
  const timezone = e.source.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  const sheetName = Utilities.formatDate(date, timezone, 'MMMM d, yyyy');
  sheet.setName(sheetName);
}
```